# MS Access Subform with fields with #Error in form view

Tags: ms-access

MS Access 2003.

I have a query behind a subform that has a sql statement like this:

```
SELECT ClientTotalInvoiceLineItems.*
     , CDate(GetWeekEnding([WeekEnding1],[WeekEnding2],[WeekEnding3],[WeekEnding4],[WeekEnding5],[WeekEnding6])) AS WeekEnding 
     , CapturedInvoices.EnteredInvoiceNo, IIf([forms]![frmClientTotalInvoices]![frmClientTotalInvoicesSub].[Form].[NewRecord]=True,0,Ccur([ContractingFeesSubtotal])) AS Subtotal
     , CCur([GSTAmount]) AS GST, CCur([TotalDue]) AS Total
     , IIf(IsNull([ctlCreated]),'',[ctlCreated] & ' by ' & [ctlCreatedBy]) AS Added 
  FROM ClientTotalInvoiceLineItems 
 INNER JOIN CapturedInvoices
    ON ClientTotalInvoiceLineItems.ctlSourceID = CapturedInvoices.CapturedInvoicedID
 ORDER BY CDate(GetWeekEnding([WeekEnding1],[WeekEnding2],[WeekEnding3],[WeekEnding4],[WeekEnding5],[WeekEnding6])) DESC;
```

When the form is on a new record I get #error in the fields starting with ccur.

So as you can see I tried to put a Form.NewRecord expression on field to test it but now MSAccess crashes when I try view in form view.

How can I get rid of those #error in the fields on a new record of a subform??

Malcolm

Answer (score 0):

There are a few methods of handling this, but one method is to have the record source of the subform initially empty, and then fill in the record source on the after insert event of the main form.

Comment: Its not until i click in the subform and start to enter data that i get this #error. Which confuses my users? OF course those ccur fields are display only not data enter fields.

Answer (score 0):

I know one possible error is that you haven't correctly nested the forms;

The main "container" form that it's on needs to be included in the statement like

```
[forms]![frmClientTotalInvoices]![frmClientTotalInvoicesSub].[Form].[NewRecord]
```

I'm assuming that `frmClientTotalInvoices` is the largest container of the form.