# Access #Error in field

Tags: ms-access, subform

I have a subform which is displayed in a main form.  The subform gets its information from a query.  Two fields have #Error in them.  The fields are calculations done by the query.

I do not get the error message when I run the database on my computer, but someone else who uses the same database does get the error.  I had the other user run the subform directly and the error did not appear.  It only appears when run as a subform on the main form.  Also note that this error was not happening before.  We are both using the latest version of access.

Comment: It's been awhile since I've worked with Access, but see if the information here might help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459474/ms-access-subform-with-fields-with-error-in-form-view ... know that there are many Google hits for the same question (add the word subform) with MANY different causes/reasons.

Comment: What are the calculations? Are the fields available and do they have data for that record?

Comment: the calculations are based on other fields in the query and the current date.  And keep in mind, i do not get the error when the sub form is run independently.